# create separate columns whose titles are based on values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create values for each location of data. I have:

```
Portafolio Zona Region COM PROV        Type of Housing
   654738   1    2      3   21             compuesto 
    65344   3    8      4   22              error
```

I want to make new columns for each of the types of housing and for their values i want to be able to count how many there are total in each portafolio, zona, region, com, and prov. I have struggled with it for 2 days and I am new to python pandas. It should look like this:

```
 Zona Region COM PROV      Compuesto      Error
   1    2      3   21         24           444 
   3    8      4   22         34            32
```

Comment: Where do the values for "Compuesto" and "Error" come from? They are not from the input data that you provided.

Comment: those are the total amount of occurrences that they appear in for each zona, region, com, and prov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `pd.pivot_table` specifying that the aggregation function is `size`

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Zona', 'Region', 'COM', 'PROV'], 
                     columns='Type of Housing',
                     aggfunc='size').reset_index()
df1.columns.name=None
```

Output: `df1`

```
   Zona  Region  COM  PROV  compuesto  error
0     1       2    3    21        1.0    NaN
1     3       8    4    22        NaN    1.0
```

Comment: Will this give me the total amount of occurrences for 'compuesto' and 'error' for PER zona, region, com, and prov?

Comment: Yes, for each unique combination of `[Zona, Region, COM, PROV]` this will count the occurences of each unique value found in `Type of Housing`

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped out a lot.